# Select 2-3 number combination from 5 column Table MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, normalization

Table structure:

```
 MyTable (
   ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
   Num1 INT,
   Num2 INT,
   Num3 INT,
   Num4 INT,
   PRIMARY KEY(ID)
 )engine=InnoDB;
```

Now i have around **20-30k** records. `Num1, Num2, Num3` and `Num4` are just some random numbers. Im trying to select `2` and `3` **number combinations** from this table. For example lets say i have the following rows in table:

```
ID    Num1   Num2   Num3   Num4
1     20     11     9      150
2     30     11     20     19
3     40     45     11     20
```

I would want to select the most frequently used **2** number combinations and then **3** number combinations. So note that **20** and **11** appear **3** times in table means the combination `20,11 or 11,20` doesnt matter the order has **count 3** and so on for other combinations.

I want to retrieve this data in PHP array so that i can do some calculations or display on screen.

What i tried so far:

```
 SELECT *
 FROM MyTable
 WHERE (Num1 = :num1 AND Num2 = :num2) OR (Num1 = :num1 AND Num3 = :num2) OR 
       (Num1 = :num1 AND Num4 = :num2) OR (Num2 = :num1 AND Num1 = :num2) OR 
       (Num2 = :num1 AND Num3 = :num2) OR (Num2 = :num1 AND Num4 = :num2) OR 
       ***
       ***
```

and so on for all combinations. Now this gets annoying if i try to use it for **3** number combinations.

1. Is there a better and efficient way of doing this?
2. Do i need to restructure table to make this easier?
3. Will restructured table be normalized? (Right now i think is normalized if not please tell me)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Case 2 combinations**

I think you should consider store information in a big matrix like this:

```
num  times_appearing_with_number_1 times_appearing_with_number_2 ...
```

For a case like

```
 1 8 2 3
 1 7 23 24
```

it would be like:

```
 num 1 2 3 4 5 6 ...
 1   - 1 1 0 0 0 ...
 2   1 - 1 0 0 0 ...
```

And then you check which lines have bigger numbers. The indexes would be useful to get the number it corresponds to.

**Case 3 combinations**

The same with a 3D-matrix.

To feed these tables you should only fetch the information from MySQL and then loop.

Comment: so you are suggesting to get all data into PHP from MySQL and then do all the work in PHP ?

Comment: Yes. In fact I based my answer on your sentence _I want to retrieve this data in PHP array so that i can do some calculations or display on screen._

Comment: yes the thing is 2 num combination is retrieved from 1 ajax call and 3 numcombination is retrieved from another ajax call. Building matrix for each ajax call is kind of redundant isnt it?

Answer (score 1):

since the order of values doesn't matter, there are only 6 permutations to pick two out of four columns (c1-c2, c1-c3, c1-c4, c2-c3, c2-c4 and c3-c4), and only four permutations to pick three (c1-c2-c3, c1-c2-c4, c1-c3-c4, c2-c3-c4).

One approach would be to create a temporary table which contains the id of the row and all 6 (4 for three cols) permutations of those values. You could use a query like this:

```
SELECT id, CASE Num1<=Num2 WHEN TRUE THEN CONCAT(Num1,"-",Num2) ELSE CONCAT(Num2,"-",Num1) END FROM MyTable
UNION
SELECT id, CASE Num1<=Num3 WHEN TRUE THEN CONCAT(Num1,"-",Num3) ELSE CONCAT(Num3,"-",Num1) END FROM MyTable
...
```

All that's left then is counting the number of matching rows (note that above query could either be run manually or as a subquery to the counting query)

Edit: Something to [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1f52e/3/0) with.

Comment: the snippet only shows two of the six queries you need to do, the others are only mentioned in the text.